# Creating a loading timeout page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a timeout page when loading certain data from the backend takes too long, but i am failing at something very easy (i think), my code currently

```
const Layout = ({ lang: { language, loadingLang }, getLang }) => {
  const time = useRef(0);
  const timer = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Get the language
    if (!language && !loadingLang) {
      getLang();
      //Start the timer
      timer.current = setInterval(function() {
        ++time.current;
        console.log(time.current);
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer.current);
      };
    }

    // Prevent any useless errors with net line:
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  if (language && !loadingLang) {
    // stop the timer if whe have the data
    clearInterval(timer.current);
  }

  if (!language && time.current > 10) {
    return <LoadingTimeoutPage />;
  }

  // If the language data does not exist or is loading show the preloader
  if (!language && time.current < 10) {
    return <Preloader />;
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/hire" component={Hire} />
        <Route exact path="/swimschool" component={SwimSchool} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard} roles={['any']} />
        <Route exact path="*" component={PDNE} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

It should be very simple i think but i just can't get it to work how it is supposed to, right now it will just show the preloader even after the 10 seconds have passed, am i doing something wrong that i am just overlooking?

Comment: You should show what function is consuming time. Is it getLang()? Does it return promise?

Comment: I don't think so, its a redux function. But yes getLang is consuming time thats why i start a timer when i run getLang

Comment: You are starting a timer but you never actually trigger a re-render when the timer value exceeds the limit. A changing ref does not tigger a re-render.

Comment: How come a function like `getLang` is time consuming?!

Comment: Ah that would explain it, what is a better way to do this then?

Comment: @bravemaster getLang gets the language info from the backend, if for whatever reason this takes to long i want to show a different page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to periodically check the timer value and trigger a re-render when it exceeded the limit:

```
const Layout = ({/* ... */}) => {
  const [limitExceeded, setLimitExceeded] = useState(false);
  const time = useRef(0);
  const timer = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!language && !loadingLang) {
      getLang();

      timer.current = setInterval(function() {
        if(time.current > 10) {
          // trigger a re-render by setting limitExceeded to true
          setLimitExceeded(true);
          clearInterval(timer.current);
        } else {
          ++time.current;
        }
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(timer.current);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (language && !loadingLang) clearInterval(timer.current);
  }, [language, loadingLang]);

  // ...

  if (!language && limitExceeded) {
    return <LoadingTimeoutPage />;
  }

  // ...
}
```